# How do I allow a user to submit multiple instances of the same form on a page and store the data using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

I am working on a php project that consists of an html form that allows the user to submit the bits of text, a song name, composer, and artist. Once the user fills in the form and clicks submit, the data should be stored and allow the form to be filled in again until the user pushes another button which shows all of the data that has been submitted. I have so far thought of using arrays, but I am not sure how that would work with multiple form submissions sending to the same array. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>

      <body>
        <form method="post">
          Name of song: <input type="text" name="songName"><br>
          Composer: <input type="text" name="composer"><br>
          Artist/Group: <input type="text" name="artist"><br>
          <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
      </body>


      <?php
        if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
          //Submit the data into the array or something here
        }
      ?>
    </html>
```

Comment: Just have the PHP code at the bottom store the posted data into the database. It will automatically display the form again unless you do something to prevent it.

Comment: I suppose you could store your results in an array inside a session. Or if they need to persist, as above, in a database.

Comment: @francisco.preller Could you possibly provide an example of what you mean? Particularly by in session.

Comment: Check the answer for details

Comment: submit the form using ajax.  the content of the form will remain intact on the page after submitting and doesn't require a full page reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, try this and see what happens:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Initialize an array for answers
    if (!isset($_SESSION['answers']))
        $_SESSION['answers'] = array();
?>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form method="post">
      Name of song: <input type="text" name="songName"><br>
      Composer: <input type="text" name="composer"><br>
      Artist/Group: <input type="text" name="artist"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
  </body>


  <?php
    if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
        // Push the posted data into the session array
        $_SESSION['answers'][] = $_POST;
    }

    // Display the data now
    foreach($_SESSION['answers'] as $array) {
        echo "Name of song: {$array['songName']}<br>";
        echo "Composer: {$array['compose']}<br>";
        echo "Artist/Group: {$array['artist']}<br><hr>";
    }
  ?>
</html>
```

**Note: SESSIONS only remain until the user logs off or they time out. For persistance over long periods, you need to use a database such as MySQL to store the answers**

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you!. I do have an additional question however. The print_r... outputs the data in a rather unappealing way. How can I print all of the data more like Song: songName, Composer: composer and so on for all of the data?

Comment: As the comment states, the print_r() method is mostly for debugging, to print it out properly you would have to use a foreach loop and then output html using `echo` See here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I have added this:                                                if (!empty($_POST['display'])){
  foreach ($_SESSION['answers'] as $value){
    echo $value;
}
}                                                                                                                                        and it simply outputs ArrayArray... for however many times the form was submitted.

Comment: This will actually print Array Array Array on your screen. This is because $_SESSION['answers'] holds a multidimensional array. What you might do is actually foreach($_SESSION['answers'] as $array) { foreach($array as $value) { echo $value; } }

Comment: Thank you again, that worked. Hopefully just one more question. It shows the Submit in the list of data, is there a way to remove that, and is there a way to label the data as it is echoed, for example Song: song name Composer: composer name?

Comment: Remove the name attribute from the submit input :) Or if you do not want to do that, just unset it from the output before putting it into the $_SESSIOn['answers'] variable. For your reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

Comment: unset worked like a charm. How about the second part of the last question?